# How to specify EOL character when using com.databricks.spark.csv format?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using the [com.databricks.spark.csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) data source  in PySpark to write a set of gzipped CSVs to HDFS, like so:

```
dataframe.write\
.mode('overwrite')\
.format('com.databricks.spark.csv')\
.options(codec='org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec', header=True)\
.save('...path...')
```

However the files are being created with Unix EOL characters, while the process that will ultimately be consuming the files requires DOS style.

Is there any way to ensure the files are created with the EOL chars I want?